# Any help to resolve this error? much appreciated! from solidity: SimpleStorage.sol:28:4: ParserError: Expected primary expression

Tags: solidity, remix, storage

How do I solve this error? I keep getting

> Expected primary expression.

when compiling using pragma solidity ^0.6.0. Here is my code. Thanks!

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract SimpleStorage {

    
    
    //this will be initialized to 0! 
     uint256 favoriteNumber;
     bool  favoriteBool;
     
     struct people {
       uint256 favoriteNumber;
        string name;
     }

    people[] public people;
    
    function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;
    }
        
    function retrieve() public view returns(uint256) {
        return favoriteNumber;
    }

    function addPerson(string memory _name, uint256 _favoriteNumber) public{ 
        people.push(people({favoriteNumber: _favoriteNumber, name: _name}),
```

Comment: The code doesn't fail with the error you mention. The code is using the same name `people` for the struct type and the variable. I'd recommend to use `People` for the struct type.

Answer (score 1):

As said @Ismael in the comment the code failed to compile because you declared with same identifier the struct name and struct array. To solve this problem, try to change this identifier in one of these variables. I adjusted your smat contract code, you can see it below:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract SimpleStorage {

    //this will be initialized to 0! 
    uint256 favoriteNumber;
    bool  favoriteBool;
     
    struct people {
        uint256 favoriteNumber;
        string name;
    }

    // NOTE: Change identifier name
    people[] public _people;
    
    function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;
    }
        
    function retrieve() public view returns(uint256) {
        return favoriteNumber;
    }

    function addPerson(string memory _name, uint256 _favoriteNumber) public{ 
        _people.push(people({favoriteNumber: _favoriteNumber, name: _name}));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I already  did changed the identifier doing multiple trials but still get this error :
SimpleStorage.sol:13:5: DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique.
    People public _People;
    ^----^ went back to line 13 People public _People; How do i solve this please

Comment: here's the updated code ,Please how do i Compile this without error Thanks in advance // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
contract SimpleStorage {
    //this will be initialized to 0!
    uint256 favoriveNumber;
    bool  favoriteBool;

    struct people {
        uint256 favoriveNumber;
        string  name;
    }
    // Note: Change identifier name
    People public _People;

    function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;
    }

Comment: function retrieve() public view returns(uint256) {
        return favoriteNumber;
    }
    function addPerson(string memory _name, uint256 _favoriteNumber) public{
        _People.push(People( {favoriteNumber: _favoriteNumber, name: _name}));
    }
}

Comment: Looking forward to hear from you soon Thanks